# Access UEFI Settings with Discrete Card Only

Tags: graphics-card, bios, uefi, amd-ryzen, discrete-graphics

I have an MSI B550 PRO-VDH paired with a Ryzen 5900X CPU (no integrated GPU) and a dedicated GPU (RTX 3080). When I tried upgrading to Windows 11, I found out TPM 2.0 is disabled in the UEFI firmware settings; in order to enable the TPM, I rebooted into Windows Advanced boot, selected *Reboot into UEFI Settings* option, but I just can't get a video image.

I have tried almost every cable combination available on the MB:

- Motherboard: HDMI and DP
- RTX Card: HDMI and DP

Is it possible to access UEFI settings using the discrete (and only) video card?

The only setting I'm missing is using the VGA adapter on the motherboard and I may be able to get a VGA monitor, however I just wanted to know if trying the VGA adapter on the motherboard would work.

Comment: This is a super standard use case. It absolutely should work. Do you see the motherboard startup sequence and the Windows logo when booting? // Perhaps try different ports on your graphics card (not on the mainboard).

Comment: I know you've already resolved this, simply some additional info: The motherboard firmware and basic video is always accessible via VGA on most mother and server boards, even without a discrete and/or integrated GPU or IPMI, as the board doesn't rely on integrated CPU graphics or a discrete GPU to output basic video. A VGA monitor isn't necessarily required, but a VGA to DP or HDMI converter would be required for an HDMI/DP only monitor _(the path of the signal matters since it isn't bidirectional - e.g. a VGA to DP or HDMI converter likely won't convert HDMI or DP to VGA)_

Comment: @JW0914 I find that very hard to believe. I have *never* heard of a board that could output any display signal at all without relying on an integrated GPU (in-CPU or in-chipset) or a dedicated GPU (either onboard or as an add-in card). VGA isn't some magic that just works.

Comment: @DanielB It was meant to say "_without a discrete and/or integrated CPU GPU or IPMI_" and appears I forgot to make that distinction in the first integrated graphics reference _(it's in the second reference, but not the first)_

Answer (score 5):

Ok, afrer a while I found out the issue.

I'm using an Odyssey G9 monitor and it has the option to "lock" the Refresh Rate. In my case it was set up to 240Hz which made my screen look black as default UEFI interface refresh rate was 60Hz.

I switched the Display Port 1.4 Cable for an old HDMI 2.0 and connected it directly to the RTX Card, which made the monitor lower the Refresh Rate to 60 Hz and boom! I was able to access the UEFI settings!